# possibly n(lgn)^2 complexity for finding number of inversions in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have seen from a lecture that there is an algorithm for counting the number of inversions in a given array that is O(nlogn). Well in an attempt to find such an algorithm I came up with the following and wanted to ask some questions regarding it .
(Assume the array has distinct elements from 1 to n)

Algorithm:

Suppose algorithm to count the number of inversions on an array of length n  does so by

1)
dividing the array by half and counting the number of inversions in each subarray

2)
for the required comparisons of elements from each subarray ,algorithm merge-sorts left subarray and for each element in the subarray finds their position in the sorted subarray , ( e.g if given array is 214365 , then consider sub arrays 214 and 365 , and also the sorted subarray 124 and now "position " of 1 is 1 , 2 is 2 and 4 is 3 in the sorted subarray)

3)

in addition one also finds the position of these elements from subarray in the sorted version of the given array (e.g position of 1 in sorted version of array is 1 , of 2 is 2 and of 4 is 4 (obviously))

4)
now for each element subtract position in sorted subarray from sorted given array to find the number of elements in the right sub array that also forms an inversion with each element ( as those numbers will be less than the given element and not contained in the left subarray) and sum those numbers

If this is clear , I think complexity can be found by :
O(n)=2O(n/2)+(n/2)lg(n/2)+nlgn=2O(n/2)+2nlgn

2 O(n/2) term is due to recursion for each subarray , (n/2)lg(n/2) term is for merge sorting left sub array , and nlgn is for finding the positions of each element in the sorted sub and original array by binary search (on average finding an element requires lgn complexity and for n elements it is nlgn) ,

from this I think complexity is n(lgn)^2

So , essentially how good is this approach if true ?

Comment: "Good" is a little vague. It works, it has the running time you calculated, there is another algorithm that runs in O(n log n).

Comment: essentially , I am satisfied that it works and my calculation is valid , so thats nice to hear

Comment: @m3h3mm3d it would be great if you post the algorithm when coded since I struggle with the same problem

Comment: I would like to know what is the algorithm in O(n log n) @DavidEisenstat

Comment: @SH there are a lot of descriptions out there, but the thumbnail is to modify mergesort so that the merge step counts inversions involving one element in each subproblem.

Comment: @SH ,I won't be writing the code here , but you can check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/ for small discussion and code for merge sort . If the code is a little bit vague , what it does is that to sort n element , divide the n elements into 2 list of n/2  elements and sort them , now assuming one is left array and the other half is right array , choose the smallest element and compare them , add small one to your final result and remove it from the list it corresponds , then again choose the smallest  element and add and so on

Comment: @SH , just for an example : suppose you are given [2,3,4,1] as input . Now you can only solve a list of length 1 , as it is already sorted , other than that you need to really do something to sort it. Now divide the list as [2,3] and [4,1] , you still do not know how to sort these 2 lists , so divide them into [2],[3] and [4],[1] and they are now sorted. Now , here is the crucial step : to merge (hence the name of the Algorithm)those sorted 1 element lists compare 2 and 3 , as 2 is less than 3 add it to some blank list .Now ignore 2 and move on to the next element in the list

Comment: But apart from 2 , there is no element in the list [2] , and as 3>2 add 3 to that initially blank list and get [2,3] as sorted. Symmetrically get [1,4] as well . Now to merge this 2 lists , choose the smallest elements 1 and 2 and compare , as 1<2 , add 1 to your final result . Move on to 4 in the list [1,4] as you did your thing about 1 in that list. Now compare 4 and 2 , 2<4 so add 2 to result , then move to 3 , 3<4 , so add 3 to result , now you looked all elemeents in one list and as the remaining list is already sorted ,in this case just [4] , add 4 and you get [1,2,3,4]

Comment: Oh ,but i think you meant about my code about less efficient one : Now again divide until you get lists of 1 element and combine them by comparing , then when you have lists of lenght >1 , as each list is sorted choose first element in one of the lists and try to find the relative position of that element if it was to be added to the second list. Do this searching by binary search ,where given a sorted list and a element x you search , compare median element of the list.

Comment: now your x is either to the right of median or left and in either case if you know in which side it is , you don't need to compare it with the other elements in other side (e.g if it is in right , so that it is bigger than median , it is also bigger than any element left of median as elements to the left of median are not bigger than median ) .Stop this process until x is bigger than one element and less than the consequent element ,as this will be reached as you smallen your search on smaller protions of your original list by ignoring halves

Comment: Also there is a solution using interval trees / segment trees. It is more intuitive, but requires more specialised knowledge.